Big Numbers not working in logic in R data.table
Can anyone explain this and suggest  a fix?
Why the false when comparing the two values?
HDup is a data table.
> HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[2]
[1] 597708127025
> HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1]
[1] 597708127025
> HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1] == HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[2]
[1] FALSE

also
> HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1] == 597708127025
[1] FALSE
> HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[2] == 597708127025
[1] FALSE

but:
> 597708127025 == 597708127025
[1] TRUE

Str(HDup) returns:
$ PROJECTED_SALES                : num  597708127025 597708127025
I suspect it's because the numbers are so large. But not sure.
it's driving me mad!

The number were most likely calculated and not imported. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059

Can you please share dput(HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1:2])?

Check what HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1] - 597708127025 gives you.

since your large numbers seem to lack decimals (and a any decimals would be irrelevant  in this ballpark) you may consider casting your data as 64 bit integers -bit64::as.integer64()  -it is a data type that plays nicely with data.table

@AndreWildberg {> dput(HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1:2])
c(597708127025.286, 597708127025.286)}

@OliverHumphreys, does your last comment answer your question?

@Roland
> HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1] - 597708127025 [1] 0.2857666
Very odd!
I've checked the data old school style in notepad++ and indeed there are decimal places that are slightly different. 0.2858 vs 0.2859 not sure where the 666 came from though!

Btw, in you case even dput truncated some digits. I bet dput(HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1:2], control="all") shows all floating point digits.

@AndreWildberg it does! Plus a few that even notepad++ isn't showing:
> dput(HDup$PROJECTED_SALES[1:2], control="all") c(597708127025.28577, 597708127025.28589)

Many thanks everyone!
